# Angular 1.2.10 upgrade kills $httpBackend tests

Tags: ajax, angularjs, unit-testing, qunit, httpbackend

I just upgraded from `Angular.js 1.1.3` to `1.2.10` and my `$httpBackend` tests started failing. Im using `QUnit 1.12.0` as a testing framework.

I have the following setup in my tests.

```
(function () {
var fittingDataServiceMock,
    injector,
    ctrl,
    $scope,
    $httpBackend;

module("Fitting Controller Test", {
    setup: function() {
        injector = angular.injector(['ngMock', 'ng','fittingApp']);
        $scope = injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
        $httpBackend = injector.get('$httpBackend');
        fittingDataServiceMock = injector.get('fittingDataService');

        //expects a post on controller creation
        $httpBackend.expectPOST('/app_dev.php/client_api/command').respond("hello");
        ctrl = injector.get('$controller')(DoubleVariableController, { $scope: $scope, fittingDataService: fittingDataServiceMock });
        $httpBackend.flush();
    },
    teardown: function() {

    }

    test ("DoubleVariableController Simple Test", function() {
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('/app_dev.php/client_api/command').respond(200, {data: "Hello"});

    // make an AJAX Posts

    $httpBackend.flush();
    }
});
```

In this case, I get two failing tests

**First Error:**

`Setup failed on DoubleVariableController Simple Test: No pending request to flush!`

```
    at Error (native)
    at Function.$httpBackend.flush (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular-mocks.js:1148:34)
```

**Second Error:**

`Died on test #2 ... No pending request to flush !`

```
Error: No pending request to flush !
    at Error (native)
    at Function.$httpBackend.flush (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular-mocks.js:1148:34)
```

I don't know why all the sudden, post requests are not going through. The tests worked fine using Angular 1.1.3. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

As 1.2.x has move ngRoute to separate file you have to include it after angular.js in your tests configuration file.